# Creating pandas DataFrame from multiple csv files with date index

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have multiple csv files with measurement data, that I would need to merge into one Pandas DataFrame with the date/time as index. I have tried using pd.concat, however, this only adds the csv files together and does not 'sort' them correctly.

Example file 1:

```
    NAME;DATE;VALUE;UNIT
    SO.DA.TT.401.3;01-01-2015 00:00:00;14,9;°C
    SO.DA.TT.401.3;01-01-2015 00:10:00;14,9;°C
```

Example file 2:

```
    NAME;DATE;VALUE;UNIT
    SO.DA.TT.401.3;16-06-2014 20:50:00;51,9;°C
    SO.DA.TT.401.3;16-06-2014 21:00:00;51,8;°C
```

How can I import the files such that they are sorted both by index and name into one DataFrame??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need list comprehension with `glob` which return filenames, then use parameters `index_col, parse_dates` for set second column to `DatetimeIndex` and parameter `decimal` for convert `VALUE` column to numeric.

Last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) list of `DataFrame`s and if necessary [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
files = glob.glob('files/*.csv')
#second column convert to datetimeindex
dfs = [pd.read_csv(fp, sep=';',index_col=[1], parse_dates=[1], decimal=',') for fp in files]
df = pd.concat(dfs).sort_index()
print (df)

                               NAME  VALUE UNIT
DATE                                           
2014-06-16 20:50:00  SO.DA.TT.401.3   51.9   °C
2014-06-16 21:00:00  SO.DA.TT.401.3   51.8   °C
2015-01-01 00:00:00  SO.DA.TT.401.3   14.9   °C
2015-01-01 00:10:00  SO.DA.TT.401.3   14.9   °C
```

Comment: What if I need the DataFrame to be in the form:

        Date                SO.DA.TT.401.1    SO.DA.TT.401.2    ....
        2014-06-16     51.9                        60.8                       ....
        i.e. each csv file is a column in the DataFrame? This would make data accessing much easier as I currenlty have to do df[df['NAME']=='SO.DA'] to access each sensor

 (I don't care abou the unit)

Comment: Do you think `df = pd.concat(dfs).sort_index().reset_index().set_index('NAME')` ?